# Compilation Error while Running Maven Project(Git Repository) through Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, testng

I have a maven project set up in Jenkins. I have made an update to the code, committed and pushed it to remote(Git Repository). I configure the jenkins with maven goal as test and click the build now, Then I get errors when compiling the classes in Jenkins. As Per I Know Maven only took those classes to test that are present under src/test/java path. When  I Was building the project through Jenkins, I got the below Compilation Error,

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ myTestMaven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\s\.jenkins\workspace\meven_jenkin_sele\myTestMaven\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/s/.jenkins/workspace/meven_jenkin_sele/myTestMaven/src/main/java/com/testingMeven/myTestMaven/App.java:[3,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/s/.jenkins/workspace/meven_jenkin_sele/myTestMaven/src/main/java/com/testingMeven/myTestMaven/App.java:[16,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.testingMeven.myTestMaven.App
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

My git Repo link `https://github.com/SACTAN/myTestMaven`

I Tried adding annotation for App.java but still same error got. When I Run the same code on my Local its working fine but not working through Jenkins. Any ideas what could be going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dependencies with scope `test` in `src/main`. If you want to use TestNG in your main code then you can remove `<scope>test</scope>` from the TestNG `dependency`in your POM.

This goes for any Maven dependency and not just TestNG. Read [Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to learn more.

Comment: I tried with the solution provided by you, but still that compilation error exist.

Comment: Forgot to update project on jenkins .@mfulton26 Thank you, Its working fine now , I have question why we cant use scope as test in pom.xml while using testng?

Comment: @sachin-bhute I've updated my answer to link to information on why. If your TestNG class is in the test folder then things will work fine how you had them but if you want to use TestNG in the main source folder then you can't scope TestNG to the test compilation and execution phases of Maven.